# What does the "+x" option in "bash +x script.sh" mean?

Tags: bash, shell-script, options

I know what `bash -x` does, but what does `bash +x` do?

Googling found no results and the manual also says nothing about it.

Comment: "Using + rather than - causes these options to be turned off." But it's kinda pointless, since it's off by default anyway. I'm going to guess it was a typo and whoever wrote intended to use `-x`

Comment: @muru I was first thinking it would negate any `xtrace` in `SHELLOPTS`, present in the environment when `bash` started, but it doesn't. So I'm also unable to find a real use for `bash +x`.  It's probably there for symmetry with all other (short) shell options.

Comment: @Kusalananda, processing options is what bash does first, so `+x` won't be able to cancel a `set -x` done by a `$BASH_ENV` file or `SHELLOPTS=xtrace`. In any case,  I wouldn't call it a duplicate as it would make sense to clarify those things here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I agree. Reopened. Feel free to provide an answer.

Answer (score 5):

`-x`, same as `-o xtrace` *enables* the `xtrace` option.

`+x`, same as `+o xtrace` *disables* it.

Those options can be passed to the interpreter for those options to be enabled / disabled upon start or to `set` (`set -o xtrace` / `set -x` / `set +o xtrace` / `set +x`) for them to be enabled / disabled at runtime.

In the case of the `xtrace` option however, that option is *not* enabled by default, and since bash processes command line options before the `$SHELLOPTS` env variable, or the initialisation file whose path is stored in `$BASH_ENV`, calling `bash` with the `+x` option is pointless:

```
$ cat env
set -o xtrace
$ BASH_ENV=env bash +x -c 'echo foo'
+ echo foo
foo
$ env SHELLOPTS=xtrace bash +x -c 'echo foo'
+ echo foo
foo
```

In both cases, `+x` was not able to cancel the `set -o xtrace` set by `$BASH_ENV` or `$SHELLOPTS`.

It would only be effective after a `-x` or `-o xtrace`:

```
$ bash -x +x -c 'echo foo'
foo
```

So one case where `bash +x ./script.sh`¹ could make sense would be if you had a `alias bash='bash -x'` (unlikely).

You could do however:

```
$ bash +B -c 'echo {a,b}'
{a,b}
```

To disable the `braceexpand` option which **is** enabled by default.

Or you could do:

```
$ env SHELLOPTS=xtrace bash -c 'set +x; echo foo'
+ set +x
foo
```

To disable `xtrace` *after* it was enabled upon processing `$SHELLOPTS`.

---

<sup>¹ note the `./` which is required to prevent `bash` from looking for `script.sh` in `$PATH` when it can't be found in the current directory.</sup>